# Grab the array of nested RestSharp elements in C#

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

[Making the response call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FBat.png)
As you can see from the example, response variable returns nested Data.Results which have an array of elements that I would like to populate on a textbox let's say. 
That said I cannot get a response.Data.Results.Elements from the rest call, it returns a list of restsharp functions only. 
[getting response.Data.results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jegrF.png)
In other words.. What logic can I use to grab every single element from the response.Data.results array list?

I've initialized my Result and RootObjectSearch classes as folows:

```
    public class Result
    {
        public string suggestion { get; set; }
        public List<List<int>> matched { get; set; }
        public string format { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObjectSearch
    {
        public int count { get; set; }
        public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `list of restsharp functions only` those are Linq functions for IEnumerable inherited objects. So i guess you're getting an `IEnumerable<RootObjectSearch>`, try to iterate through it's items.

Comment: Sorry can you give me an example, I didn't get it.

Comment: Yes, I read something wrong, but the answer wopuld be very simmilar, let me add an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RootObjectSearch class has a List of Results, so to process each item from it you must iterate on that collection:

```
foreach(var result in response.Data.results)
{
    //process result here
    var asAnString = result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gusman, though my question still stands unfortunately :)
I dont know how to process the for loop if I can't extract individual elements from response.Data.results as they dont exist. List of huge functions do.. but nothing I can write to post the result.ToString() on each line per element.

Comment: That's what is extracted on the for loop... look at the update, maybe then you can understand it now.

Comment: Do you know how a foreach loop works? (not trying to offend, just is what it seems from your comment)

Comment: I think so, iterating through the collection of records but I'm unsure on how would I extract them into a field/textbox or anything since I can't get those elements in the array from response.Data.results.

Comment: you already have them, "result" inside the for loop is one of the instances of the results, so each time the for iterates "result" will contain one of the results instance.